# Is it possible to change the attribute value in the enum?

Tags: python, python-3.x, enums

I need to reassign the attribute value in Enum.

```
from enum import Enum    

class Number(Enum):
    number = "1"
    
Number.number = "2" # AttributeError: cannot reassign member 'number'
```

I tried to reassign the attribute, but I got:

> AttributeError: cannot reassign member 'number'

Comment: It violates logic of `Enum`, why do you need to change it?

Comment: "I need to reassign the attribute value in Enum." Why? What concrete problem do you hope to solve this way?

Comment: @OlvinRoght have a scenario when I check if the enum value is x, so change it to y

Comment: @an0ym, `Enum` is designed to be set of named constants. Logic you described is quite different, maybe you should use simple class?

Comment: @OlvinRoght In my situation, the framework that the company created works with the enum

Comment: @an0ym, `Enum` is not a data container, it's a constant. If you receive values in runtime, maybe you should initialize it dynamically.

Comment: This is possible but it should never be done in real code. Enumerations, by design, should never have their value changed after the initial definition. Whatever you are trying to achieve should be done in a different way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Author's note: This is a horrible idea.

---

Let's just delete the string `"1"` from Python and replace it with `"2"`

```py
from ctypes import c_byte
from enum import Enum
from sys import getsizeof


def change_enum_value(old: object, new: object) -> None:
    """
    Assigns contents of new object to old object.
    The size of new and old objection should be identical.

    Args:
        old (Any): Any object
        new (Any): Any object
    Raises:
        ValueError: Size of objects don't match
    Faults:
        Segfault: OOB write on destination
    """
    src_s, des_s = getsizeof(new), getsizeof(old)
    if src_s != des_s:
        raise ValueError("Size of new and old objects don't match")
    src_arr = (c_byte * src_s).from_address(id(new))
    des_arr = (c_byte * des_s).from_address(id(old))
    for index in range(len(des_arr)):
        des_arr[index] = src_arr[index]


class Number(Enum):
    number = "1"


change_enum_value(Number.number.value, "2")
print(Number.number.value)  # 2
```

---

You don't have the `"1"` anymore, quite literally.

```
>>> "1"
'2'
>>>
```

which sure is a tad concerning...

Comment: Thanks, it's working, but we should change our framework code structure and avoid using the enum if we want to reassign the values.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the [enum](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html) Python documentation:
The attributes, in your case Number.number, etc., are enumeration members (or members) and are functionally **constants**.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community ; Link added to the python documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When using Enum, your `number = "1"` is considered as one of the enum entry.

So, firstly, it is thought to be used this way, for example :

```
from enum import Enum


class Number(Enum):
    numberOne = "1"
    numberTwo = "2"
```

By the way, when you access to `Number.number`, you access to the "enum item", which is more than just the value. The item has, indeed, a name (`number`) and a value (`"1"`).

So, in theory, the good way to change the value should be :

```
Number.number.value = "2"
```

But, in any was, an Enum is made to not be mutable. So you can't do that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, an Enum is a way to give "nicer names" to "constants" and then use the nicer names in your code rather than using the constants.

This intent is implemented by Python by making the enum members as "functionally constant" ... See [Python Enum Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html).

The names associated with Enums are not like variables.

Hence you cannot change the value of the name.